# which GUI based C++ IDE is commonly used for gnome applications

Tags: linux, ide, g++, gnome

which GUI based C++ IDE is commonly used for developing gnome applications?

I am asking specifically for the *gnome-system-monitor* because I would like to fiddle around with it. And I would like to do it with a nice GUI based C++ IDE.

I thought that Anjuta is the default IDE for gnome applications. But when I fetch the sources there are no files which are obviously project files.

**EDIT**: Here is what I did so far

```
# get the build dependencies for the gnome-system-monitor
sudo aptitude  build-dep gnome-system-monitor

# get the sources for the gnome-system-monitor
mkdir example
cd example
apt-get source gnome-system-monitor

# build the gnome-system-monitor
cd  gnome-system-monitor-2.28.0
sh configure
make
```

But nothing inside *gnome-system-monitor-2.28.0* looks like a "project file".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply "create project from existing sources" in Anjuta. Anjuta's "project files" do not contain a lot of information, instead the Makefile.am and configure.ac files are used.

I have no idea what the gnome-system-monitor developers use, but I've read that a lot of Gnome developers use emacs, which apparently also doesn't require "project files".

Answer (score 1):

I believe [Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/) is used, or at least was used at the time.

BTW, I'm not sure Gnome is C++. There are C++ wrappers, like gtkmm and glibmm, but I believe that core Gnome is written in C.

Comment: do you know where I can find the "project files" ?

Comment: I don't think there are project files like the ones you'll find in VisualStudio on Windows. It uses automake/autoconf as the build system.

Comment: I don't care about C/++ for this specific topic. But I *need* the "project files"